# Visual Studio 2010 Pro: Shared test project, but developer-specific connection strings

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

We have multiple developers working on the same unit test project that have unique database connection strings and user credentials.

What's the best way to store this information on a per-developer basis on their local machines, so we're not always editing a source file that gets checked into our VCS and (hopefully) reverting our changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your work environment configuration and your specific needs, using a local XML file could be a good solution. You would need to read the XML file contents programmatically, of course. You may want to edit your original question and add more details about whether or not this is feasible.

Comment: So, we would just hope the developers don't check the external configuration file into VCS?  Is there any way to configure Mercurial to say 'Never let a user check a file in named "foo.xml"'?

Comment: Name the files after the developers. My file would be CesarGon.config.xml, yours would be David.config.xml, etc. You can safely check them in that way and use the VCS features on them.